# Alter constraint in production database

Tags: oracle

I have to alter a constraint in production database. Can i drop the constraint and recreate it again? But the table is having millions of records in prod environment. Will it be a problem?

just alter constraint for on delete cascade.

Do i have to rename the table and create table with original table name with proper constraints and import data from renamed table? I am more concerned about the prod database records.

Please advice.

Comment: It depends on data, constraint you have and the constraint's change. I guess you should be more specific about your change.

Comment: I am going to add on delete cascade to the existing constraint.

Comment: i don't think you have a lot of options here. you must drop the constraint and recreate it.

Comment: Data wont be effected during mentioned alter statement but if someone can confirm if any lock will be triggered during execution of this statement that needs to be checked accordingly you can select time window.

Comment: It depends on whether the application is still running when you're doing the maintenance. When you drop the ref constraint, users *might* be able to insert rows which violate the constraint - and when you try to recreate it, it will fail. You may need to consider using Oracle's **Online Table Redefinition** feature: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables007.htm#ADMIN01514